# Run Postman jetpack test thought Newman commands

Tags: unit-testing, postman, newman

I'm using the Postman Jetpacks tests collections, they work very well, but I must run the test inside the Postman application.

Actually I need to run the tests I designed in Postman Jetpack using a command line to make it scriptable. My approach is to use Newman commands line to be able to execute the test collections. However looks like I can only execute requests using Newman instead of tests collections or even isolated tests.

Is it posible to run tests collection created on Jetpack with Newman?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I found out that is possible to execute Postman Jetpack collections with Newman, Newman will also pass the tests and display the information properly.

This is an interesting way to do Integration tests in for APIs

Comment: Indeed. And for those interested, here is the repo for Newman: https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/